# Aligning digits in table with percentage sign on first row

Tags: tables, siunitx

I'd like to align the digits taking into account the percent symbols on the first row.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{}rrrr@{}}\toprule
            Col1 & Col2 & Col3 & Col4\\ \midrule
            10\% & 20\% & 30\% & 40\%\\
            5    &  6   &  7   &  8  \\
          115    &116   &117   &118  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

[image]

However, I'd like to align the digits as shown in this image, taking into account the percent symbol on the first row and indenting the following numbers accordingly.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your readers will not be sure that every entry refers to a percentage: state it in the header.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  *{2}{S[table-format=3.0]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
Debt/Assets & {2003} & {2004} \\
            & {(\%)} & {(\%)}   \\
\midrule
\SI{<50}{\percent}           & {--} &  10 \\
\SIrange{50}{59.9}{\percent} &  20  &   5 \\
\SIrange{60}{69.9}{\percent} & {--} &  10 \\
\SIrange{70}{79.9}{\percent} & {--} &  10 \\
\SIrange{80}{89.9}{\percent} &  40  &  10 \\
\SI{\ge90}{\percent}         &  40  &  55 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(l){3-3}
Total                        & 100  & 100 \\
Mean                         &  85  &  80 \\
Median                       &  85  &  94 \\
\midrule
Number of projects           & {5}  & {20} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The final `\midrule` helps in making clear that the row is about different data.

[image]

If you prefer the bad style in the picture…

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\newcommand{\dashpercent}{%
  \makebox[1.5em][r]{--\makebox[0pt][l]{\,\%}}%
}
\newcommand{\dash}{\makebox[1.5em][r]{--}}%
\newcommand{\ppercent}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\,\%}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  *{2}{S[table-format=3.0]@{\hspace{1.2em}}}
  @{}
}
\toprule
Debt/Assets & {2003} & {2004} \\
\midrule
\SI{<50}{\percent}           & {\dashpercent} &  10\ppercent \\
\SIrange{50}{59.9}{\percent} &  20  &   5 \\
\SIrange{60}{69.9}{\percent} & {\dash} &  10 \\
\SIrange{70}{79.9}{\percent} & {\dash} &  10 \\
\SIrange{80}{89.9}{\percent} &  40  &  10 \\
\SI{\ge90}{\percent}         &  40  &  55 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
Total                        & 100\ppercent  & 100\ppercent \\
Mean                         &  85\ppercent  &  80\ppercent \\
Median                       &  85\ppercent  &  94\ppercent \\
\midrule
Number of projects           & {5}  & {20} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree this is better. But it doesn't really answer the question :-)

Comment: @SandyG Now you can use bad style, if you so wish. `;-)`

Comment: Ha! I like my bad style better than your bad style!

Answer (score 3):

You could define a `\phantom` `%` symbol:

```
\newcommand{\pct}{\phantom{\%}}
```

Then

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}rrrr@{}}\toprule
    Col1 & Col2 & Col3 & Col4\\ \midrule
    10\% & 20\% & 30\% & 40\%\\
    5\pct    &  6\pct   &  7\pct   &  8\pct  \\
    115\pct   &116\pct   &117\pct   &118\pct  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

produces the desired output, without the `%` sign going past the edge of the column.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily redefine `\%` as an `\rlap`.  Also, extend the table on the right by the width of a `\%`.  The advantage is the content of the `tabular` definition does not change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \let\svpc\%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\%}
    \edef\tmp{\the\wd0}
    \renewcommand\%{\rlap{\svpc}}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}rrrr@{\hspace{\tmp}}}\toprule
            Col1 & Col2 & Col3 & Col4\\ \midrule
            10\% & 20\% & 30\% & 40\%\\
            5    &  6   &  7   &  8  \\
          115    &116   &117   &118  \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]